# Electric quadrupole allowed transitions mathematical proof

Tags: atomic-physics, quantum-chemistry, multipole-expansion, fermis-golden-rule

Consider the electric quadruple moment operators as follows:

$Q_{20} = \frac{e}{2}(x^2+y^2-2z^2) $

$Q_{2 \pm1} = \frac{e\sqrt{6}}{2}z(x\pm iy) $

$Q_{2 \pm2} = - \frac{e\sqrt{6}}{4}(x\pm iy)^2  $

I know that the Electric quadrupole transitions are as follows:

$$\Delta l = 0, \pm 2$$
$$\Delta m_l = 0, \pm1, \pm 2$$

I was wondering how to prove these results as well as what would be the allowed n transitions. I tried using fermis golden rule but couldn't really come up with anything signficiant.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think there is an extra $z$ in $Q_{2\pm 2}$

Comment: I just checked and I don't believe there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the identity:

\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi Y_{l_1}^{m_1}(\theta,\phi)Y_{l_2}^{m_2}(\theta,\phi)&Y_{l_3}^{m_3}(\theta,\phi)\sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi
=\\
&\sqrt{\frac{(2l_1+1)(2l_2+1)(2l_3+1)}{4\pi}} \left( {\begin{array}{ccc} l_1 & l_2 & l_3  \\ 0 & 0 & 0  \\ \end{array} } \right) \left( {\begin{array}{ccc} l_1 & l_2 & l_3  \\ m_1 & m_2 & m_3  \\ \end{array} } \right)
\end{align}

to find selection rules for the matrix element in Fermi's Golden Rule:

$$ M_{i\rightarrow f} \propto \langle l_f, m_f|Q_{2m}|l_i, m_i\rangle $$

?

Note that:

$$ Q_{2m} \propto Y_l^m(\theta, \phi)$$

Comment: I tried working out the Q2+-2 one and deducing the spherical harmonic integral but  I deduced that Q22 was proprtional to the (Y1+-1 Spherical Harmonic)^2 and that meant that I was unable to proceed as I had a spherical harmonic integral with 4 spherical harmonics multiplied by one another and was unsure how to proceed from there.

Comment: $|Y_1^1|^2 \propto Y_2^2 $ is not different from $|1,1\rangle |1,1\rangle = |2,2\rangle$ with  $|j_1,m_1\rangle |j_2,m_2\rangle \rightarrow |J,M\rangle$

Comment: Just to confirm then if I deduce that the the angular part of the integral is $\int Y^*_{l', m_l'} (Y_{1 \pm1})^2 Y_{l,m_l}$ then the selection rules are $\Delta l = \pm2 $ and $\Delta m = \pm2.$

Comment: but the quadruple operators are $Y_2^m$, why are you using $(Y_1^m)^2$?

Comment: Well we know that 
$Q_{2 \pm2} = - \frac{e\sqrt{6}}{4}(x\pm iy)^2  $
and we also know that 


$\frac{1}{\sqrt2} (x \pm iy) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}r sin(\theta) e^{\pm i \phi}  = \mp \sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{3} }rY_{1\pm1}(\theta,\phi)$

So combining this we can see that $Q_{2 \pm2} \propto (Y_{1\pm1}(\theta,\phi))^2 $